# Can't crawl hidden form content not shown in the page source

Tags: forms, web, web-scraping, web-crawler, hidden

I have to crawl the comments in this web page: https://myglu.org/statuses/6587/comments
In this web page, there is one post and  several other users' comments..

### From the page source, I can see a form and the following HTML, but the source doesn't show any of the users' comments contents.

```
      <div class="comment-form">
  <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_comment"   id="new_comment" action="/statuses/6587/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
      <div class="input hidden comment_photo_id"><input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="comment[photo_id]" id="comment_photo_id" /></div>
      <div class="input text required comment_body"><label class="text required" for="comment_body"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Comment body</label><textarea class="text required" name="comment[body]" id="comment_body">
```

---

the web page is like this:

===========
Thumb Plus1always in MANAGING DIABETES WHEN... 4 months ago
Due to stress, I have no appetite and eat only to survive.  Separating from my husband, I have no insurance, fighting to keep my 3 kids, and my ex fil gave me two weeks to vacate the house he owns but we'd been living in... Trying to keep up in college classes and maintain my GPA and also trying to find a full time position so that I can support myself and my kids and stay in college (only 1 year left and student teaching).  Life is pushing me down and my tummy hates food, so soup and boost shakes it is :(

****8 Comments last comment by  User CathyL 3 months ago

▼
 Thumb GluAnna 06/17/2015
Aww keep your head up! FOcus on one day at a time and make sure you can try and take time for you! Sounds like you're doing the best you can with all that you have going on!

▼
 Thumb elizabetta 06/18/2015
I'm so sorry to hear this! You should look into applying for the free insulin programs at Lilly and Novo Nordisk for folks struggling with income/insurance issues. Also, some endos have sample bottles they can give you. Keeping you in my thoughts.

## ...

When I open the website in a browser,  I can see the 8 comments.
if you mouse click "8 Comments" (a button),it will show or hide the comments below.

How do I crawl them when the source code doesn't show the form content?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  I have edited your question a bit to make it easier to read and answer.  Note that you don't need the `snippet` markup around formatted code unless you want it to be runnable (for instance to render a webpage with javascript - but your example didn't do that).  Note also - the link you provide requires a signup to access, so most people will not be able to see it.  If you can find a similar link that doesn't require signup, that will be useful.  Good luck!

Comment: maybe the comments are grabbed using ajax (client-side asynchronous javascript http request). if so, you should be able to find the comments endpoint (i.e. the url that the ajax call is made to) by reading the javascript code. then, you can access the comments by making your own ajax call to the same endpoint

Comment: thanks. I don't it is ajax or not. The source only shows javascript.   Do you mean after you have the url address and call ajax so I can get the comments, I have extracted the url address "https://myglu.org/statuses/6587/comments", do you know how to call ajax in python?